# 'import matplotlib' gives 'module not found error'

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip, python-3.7

`pip install matplotlib` 
says `requirement already satisfied`. 
I'm on a Mac and have looked through tons of answers online but can't get matplotlib to work. I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Make sure you are using the same version of python and pip - i.e pip3 for python3. The best way is probably by using `python -m pip install matplotlib` then the same python binary when trying to run the script

Comment: When I run this command, it says `no module named pip`. I've also tried with `pip3`. How do I ensure that python and pip are using the same version?

Comment: Specify the path of the python interpreter in full for both the -m pip install part and the script execution part: e.g. `/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install matplotlib; /use/bin/python3 script_name.py`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you install it in one venv and try to import in other one.

Answer (score 0):

maybe your Interpreter is set to python not python3 ?

if you using pip3 it'S working ?

Comment: When I open `python` and `import matplotlib`, it works. But it doesn't work with `python3`. I think it is an issue with the version, like was mentioned above, but I'm unable to resolve it.